# pass array to sub, push and unshift - array is not extended as expected

Tags: arrays, perl

```
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
my @arr = [1];
wrap(\@arr);
dump(@arr);
sub wrap {
    my @a = @_;
    push @a,2;
    unshift @a, 0;
    dump(@a);
}
```

result:

[1]

(0, [[1]], 2)

There are two issues here:

1. pass an array by ref to a sub - and expect it to be modified afterward
2. why push and unshift don't just extend the array - what's that array nesting?

(new to perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @arr = [1];
```

This creates an array with one item in it -- and that item is an array reference to an anonymous array (created by using square brackets) containing your `1`.  You probably should've gone with `my @arr = (1);`

```
wrap(\@arr);
```

That's fine - it passes a reference to your `@arr` array.

```
sub wrap {
    my @a = @_;
```

You don't dereference this, so now your `@a` array contains an array reference containing an array reference containing `1`.  Your array would look something like this: `@a = ( [ [ 1 ] ] )`

```
    push @a, 2;    # @a = ([[1]], 2);
    unshift @a, 0; # @a = (0, [[1]], 2);
```

Inside `wrap` you'd have a scalar array reference in the arguments, so you'd put it in a scalar instead of an array:

```
    my ($aref) = @_; # or:  my $aref = shift;
```

and dereference it with a leading `@`:

```
    push @$aref, 2;
    unshift @$aref, 0;
```

See also [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: I read that [] defines array and () defines list which is immutable - therefore I used []

Comment: `[]` creates an anonymous array and returns a reference to it. (but you don't want a reference here.)  `()` has almost nothing to do with lists, it just adjusts precedence (e.g. my @x=1 is fine and assigns a one element list; my @x=1,2 doesn't work because it is interpreted as (my @x=1),2; my @x=(1,2) is what you commonly see, but the parentheses only serve to make the assignment get the result of the , list-concatenation operator as its right operand instead of having the `,` operator get the result of the asssignment as its left operand)